# floating a div into left

Tags: html, css, divide

Just want to make all my div of list to float to left like this one

[image]

just having a hard time and wondering where did i go wrong there, did i put a wrong division or something

my css

```
.list_wrapper{
width:200px;
background-color:red;
display:block;}



.list_wrapper2{
width:900px;
background-color:blue;
float:left;
}
```

My html

```
    <div class = "list_wrapper2" >
<h3><?php echo $letter?></h3>

<?php foreach($pages as $page): ?>
            <div class = "list_wrapper" >
            <ul>
                <li class="listcss">
                <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/page.php?page=<?php echo e($page['slug']);?>"><?php echo e($page['label']);?></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endfor; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how this is a PHP question, it's entirely a CSS problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: Where is the list_wrapper CSS class in your HTML?

Comment: sorry i put the wrong htm code

Comment: `.list { float: left; }` as easy as this

Comment: @RaymartCalinaoAsthreA : Please add correct code

Comment: `float:left` will wrap the div's to next line on overflow!!

Comment: display: inline-block, will help.

Comment: tried inline block in listwrapper but it didn't work

Comment: sorry gonna delete the php tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left`. Here is an example to get started.

**Note:** `float` will wrap the div's to next row on overflow!

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: which part of my div is the wrapper you are suggesting outside the forloop or inside?

Comment: @RaymartCalinaoAsthreA : Outside

Answer (score 0):

Your code example contains too much irrelevant information.
In order to achieve the desired result just add a class with `float: left` to each div.

```css
.floating-left{
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="floating-left"></div>
<div class="floating-left"></div>
<div class="floating-left"></div>
<div class="floating-left"></div>
<div class="floating-left"></div>
<div class="floating-left"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.list_wrapper2
```

Width is to large,  unless you're body width is like 3000px.
Reduce the width to something like 200px and they should float properly.

Answer (score 0):

try remove width property, because two divs needs 1800px width, so they can't float to the left of each other